# Use Buttons to control displayed images, ASP NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have tried to due my research before posting as a question, most searched I have performed are providing me guides to creating buttons with images in them which is not what I need.

I am starting off with a data structure, that represents 3 categories, with a collection of items in each category that map to images. The actual format is a CSV, but I will show in JSON to clarify

```
{ 
"Category1": "1, 2",
"Category2": "3, 4, 5",
"Category3": "6, 7, 8, 9"
}
```

with the raw actual being where I would need 2 button sets, one set for category one for price, but I can take a base example and make it work. `Category1:Price1-1,Price2-2;Category2:Price1-3,4Price2-5;Category3:Price1-6,Price2-7,8,9`

The categories are not fixed, so the data must be read to determine the text for each button.

I would like three toggle buttons, one for each category. If a button is selected all the items from that category will be rendered on the page. Numbers have a 1:1 mapping with images like "1.jpg". Images should be in a list.

So far, I am able to show all the data. But I can not figure out how to add these buttons to hide a category. This has been done the aspx page, and not in the aspx.cs. The aspx page is very poorly done, but I did not want to work to hard on it because I think most of the logic for this should be in C#.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p runat="server">
            Price 1: <% =GetCat1()%>
        </p>
        <div>
            <img style="margin-top: 20px; width: 210px;" src="./Hotel/<% =GetCat1Ad1()%>.jpg" />
            <img style="margin-top: 20px; width: 210px;" src="./Hotel/<% =GetCat1Ad2()%>.jpg" />
            <img style="margin-top: 20px; width: 210px;" src="./Hotel/<% =GetCat1Ad3()%>.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p runat="server">
            Price 2: <% =GetCat2()%>
        </p>
        <div>
            <img style="margin-top: 20px; width: 210px;" src="./Hotel/<% =GetCat2Ad1()%>.jpg" />
            <img style="margin-top: 20px; width: 210px;" src="./Hotel/<% =GetCat2Ad2()%>.jpg" />
            <img style="margin-top: 20px; width: 210px;" src="./Hotel/<% =GetCat2Ad3()%>.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p runat="server">
            Price 3: <% =GetCat3()%>
        </p>
        <div>
            <img style="margin-top: 20px; width: 210px;" src="./Hotel/<% =GetCat3Ad1()%>.jpg" />
            <img style="margin-top: 20px; width: 210px;" src="./Hotel/<% =GetCat3Ad2()%>.jpg" />
            <img style="margin-top: 20px; width: 210px;" src="./Hotel/<% =GetCat3Ad3()%>.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "three toggle buttons for each category" or "three toggle buttons - one for each category"?

Comment: and, please, wrap your `GetAd3` calls in another function with minimal number of parameters - my eyes hurt when I look at these 300-character lines

Comment: cleaned up provided code